# Faceting messes up value labels in heatmap (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, facet

I'm making a heatmap using ggplot2. I want to put the values themselves inside the heatmap boxes, but I'm finding that while that works okay when not faceting, as soon as I facet, the numbers go to all the wrong boxes - see attached pictures. Any tips on how to make the numbers stay in the right boxes when faceting?

ALso, some other minor questions: how to change the tile sizes when and when not faceting; changing the color of the value text in the boxes (<- tried the obvious solutions but don't seem to work...)

Thanks everyone!

Code (Can see where the facet is commented out):

```
fpdata<-read.csv("fp.csv",header=T)
fpdata$Dimension=factor(fpdata$Dimension,levels(fpdata$Dimension)[c(4,1,3,2,5)])
fpdata$Trait=factor(fpdata$Trait,levels(fpdata$Trait)[c(22,15,16,3,4,9,21,20,10,14,6,2,1,
                                                        13,8,11,12,17,24,25,18,5,23,19,7)])
matrix <- melt(fpdata)
matrix
matrix$value[is.na(matrix$value)] <- 2
matrix


p3 <- ggplot(data = matrix, aes(variable, Trait, fill = value))+
  geom_tile(color = "white")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "firebrick", mid = "deepskyblue", 
                         midpoint = 0.6, limit = c(0.6,1), space = "Lab", 
                         name="Factor Loadings")+labs(x = "Reduction #")+
    geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(matrix$value<2,matrix$value," ")))
  ##+facet_grid(~Dimension, scale="free") 

p3 <- p3 +  
  theme (axis.title.x = element_text(size=20),
         axis.title.y = element_text(size=20),
         axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 1, size = 14, hjust = 0.5),
         axis.text.y = element_text(size=16),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         legend.title = element_text(size=16),
         legend.text = element_text(size=14),
         strip.text.x = element_text(size=13, face="bold"))+coord_fixed()
p3
```

Heat Map without Facet

[image]

Heat Map with Facet

[image]

Comment: never use `$` inside `aes()`; define a variable in the dataframe outside ggplot2 instead

Comment: @baptiste ? I tried changing it so that there was a newvar<-matrix$value then replaced m$v in the geom_text aes with newvar, but the issue was still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(trait = sample(letters, 15),
                 dimension = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 3), 
                 variable = paste0('R', 1:3), 
                 value = runif(15))

ggplot(df, aes(variable, trait, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = ifelse(value > 0.25, value, NA))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(value > 0.25, round(value, 2), NA))) +
  facet_grid(~dimension, scales = 'free')
```

Reproducible example I hope mirrors your data somewhat. As suggested above, value is already defined in your input (df$value) in this case. So you can refer to it directly as a bare (unquoted) symbol.